# HTML5 Local Storage not storing value from password box

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have written a HTML file, and it contains two entry boxes, one is called username and the other called password. Something like this:

```
<input class='registerinput' id='registerusername' placeholder='Username'></input>
<input class='registerinput' id='registerpassword' placeholder='Password' type='password'></input>
<input class='registerinput' id='registerpasswordrepeat' placeholder='Repeat Password' type='password'></input>
```

And I want to store it into a local storage using these codes.

```
if (document.getElementById('registerusername').value != "") {
    localStorage.username=document.getElementById('registerusername').value }
else if (document.getElementById('registerusername').value == "") {
    alert('You must enter a username.') } 
if (document.getElementById('registerpassword').value != "" && document.getElementById('registerpasswordrepeat').value == document.getElementById('registerpassword').value) {
    localStorage.password==document.getElementById('registerpassword'.value) }
else if (document.getElementById('registerpassword').value == "") {
    alert('You must enter a password') }
if (document.getElementById('registerpasswordrepeat').value != document.getElementById('registerpassword').value) {
    alert('The password did not match.') }
```

Everything worked except I cannot save the value in password box. Is it a HTML5 storage limitation for security or a bug in my code? Thanks.

Comment: I checked it using an alert and it returned the correct value for username but null for password. Strange.

Comment: nitpick: store the values into variables and use the variables, it will make your code 100% easier to read.

Comment: You have == instead of = in your assignment as well as a missing closing paren

Comment: It is not wise to store sensitive information (credentials are among the most sensitive data available :-)) in localstorage. It's like storing user passwords in clear text somewhere in the file system.

Answer (score 2):

Before answering, please note that there may be browsers in the wild that don't support this, and you can detect this as follows:

```
if(window.localStorage) {
    // do your local storage stuff here
} else {
    // do something else instead as localStorage is not available
}
```

Aside from this information, here's your typo:

```
localStorage.password==document.getElementById('registerpassword'.value) }
```

You're missing the parentheses after the closing `'`.

Comment: Hmm. I use the function from W3Schools... Okay, I will try it when I'm free. Now I can't do my coding with this iPad. But why username works with my code? It returns the correct value for me.

Comment: You know what, user27731, you may have just taught me something new. Surprisingly, when I set `localStorage.name = "james"` and reloaded, the value still contained my name... I'll edit the post to make it more.... correct... but first, do you have IE handy (I'm on a Mac). Does this work in IE?

Comment: Just tested in IE, works in IE10 and IE8... ok... editing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As jmort253 points out it can be wise to check for browser support even though virtually all browsers supports `localStorage` (but the one that really need to use your app is the one that doesn't...).

And also change this line (double = and end-parenthesis in the wrong place):

```
localStorage.password==document.getElementById('registerpassword'.value)
```

to:

```
localStorage.password = document.getElementById('registerpassword').value;
```

However, the more "correct" syntax for `localStorage` is to use:

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

which you retrieve with:

```
var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
```

which gives you the value as `String` or `null` if it does not exist (the direct property way will as always give `undefined` if key does not exist).

Another tip to make it easier to avoid typos such as this is to centralize your variables, for example:

```
var password1 = document.getElementById('registerpassword').value,
    password2 = document.getElementById('registerpasswordrepeat').value;

if (password1.length > 0 && password1 === password2) { ... }
```

This way you can discover more easily if an error occurs (and as a bonus it's a bit faster as well).

Comment: Hi Ken, excellent answer! But why would you say the setItem/getItem is more correct? *(It's definitely more along the lines of what I'm used to seeing, but the op's format appears to work in Chrome and IE... didn't test Firefox though...)*

Comment: Hi @jmort253 and thanks. It's just details :) I just say it because it's more clean and outlined in the official document as well as being [the recommended way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FStorage). I put correct in quotes as the other ways aren't wrong and will work but it doesn't hurt (IMO) to "promote" (?) adoption of the official standard :)